How to find out if an object is reachable by garbage collector in java?
Is there a way to manually find out if an object is available for garbage collection or to somehow trigger the garbage collector? Also, How I can specify GC type in IntelliJ IDEA?
I know about the command System.gc(), but what exactly happens when the JVM sees this command? How is it decided whether the garbage collector will work or not? Also, in which situations it is necessary to use this command?

check if it's null or not. you can't force the GC, you can "request" it

You can't check if an object is available for garbage collection, unless you definitely know all possible places where that object could possibly be referenced, then check that nothing references it. Also, it is rarely necessary to call System.gc() - all it does is to indicate a desire for garbage collection to be attempted, but there is no guarantee that anything would be garbage-collected even if available.

How I can specifiy GC type in IntelliJ IDEA?  and a few of the options.

@Stultuske Objects aren’t null. References are null. References aren’t objects.

You can check with a WeakReference or a PhantomReference, but there is hardly ever a good reason to want to do this. There is even less of a good reason to call System.gc(). Java is usually better at knowing when to GC than you are, and code that calls System.gc() almost always is an indication that the programmer doesn't know what they're doing.

This looks to be an XY Problem. You should provide more clarity into what are you trying to achieve, what is the original problem you are trying to resolve.


Is there a way to manually find out if an object is available for garbage collection or to somehow trigger the garbage collector? Also, How I can specify GC type in IntelliJ IDEA?

So, looking at the question, I would ask this when I want to have determination and/or control on the lifetime of an object. Maybe I want to get rid of it out of a cache, or maybe I want to safeguard heap memory and have the least important objects cleaned by the GC.
Taking this into consideration, then I believe it would be good for you to do the following :

Study Strong, Soft, Phantom and Weak references in Java.
In short, most references to an object are "Strong References", meaning that they will never be collected by the GC unless they are de-referenced (i.e. variable to the value set to null, leaving the object un-referenced and ready for GC to clear it out)

Look to use "Weak References" to somewhat determine what you want out. This way you have references that you know you don't need existing if a memory clearing event happens (then the weak references and their referents are first in the firing line).
WeakReference< YourObject > weakReferencedObject = new WeakReference<>(new YourObject());


Re: Intellij GC settings :
1 Open Run/Debug Configurations

Go to "Run" > "Edit Configurations"
Select your application
configuration

2.Add VM Options:

On the "VM Options" field, add the desired garbage collector flags, e.g.
-XX:+UseZGC or whatever GC you have available from the JVM type you are running.


I know about the command System.gc(), but what exactly happens when
the JVM sees this command? How is it decided whether the garbage
collector will work or not? Also, in which situations it is necessary
to use this command?

Run away ASAP from the code smell of using this!
According to Oracle themselves, they discourage the use of it, on https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#gc(). The following is taken from that link :

There is no guarantee that this effort will recycle any particular number of
unused objects, reclaim any particular amount of space, or complete at
any particular time, if at all, before the method returns or ever.
There is also no guarantee that this effort will determine the change
of reachability in any particular number of objects, or that any
particular number of Reference objects will be cleared and enqueued.

Also to keep in mind, generally when some GC algorithms run they trigger like as they say a "stop the world" event, which means all your JVM threads have to kind of pause at a safepoint/snapshot-point whilst GC collects garbage (or does something like marking de-referenced objects for collection etc, depending on the algorithm). Even in the other collectors which might not act exactly like this there is in most times a cost to performance when GC is run. You have to measure the cost to your application, on whether it's worth it or not. One person's negligible cost may be another one's SLA breaking point.

If you want to do this for cleanup actions, the "modern" way would be to use Cleaner (which behind the scenes uses a PhantomReference IIRC).
